# Alignment of abbreviations in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to align to left the abbreviations in a list made with biblatex? By default the abbreviation (shorthand) comes ragged left whereas the details of the work are justified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=nyt,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{3pt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{barreiros1968chorographia,
    author    = {Barreiros, G.},
    title     = {Chorographia de alguns lugares [...]},
    year      = {1561},
    publisher = {por Ioã Aluarez},
    url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=h3-RngEACAAJ},
    address   = {em Coimbra},
    keywords  = {Gaspar Barreiros -- toponímia (latina e portuguesa) -- geografia (história) -- Ânio de Viterbo (recepção) -- sigla},
    shorthand = {BCor},
}
@Book{Teixeira1583,
    author    = {Teixeira, frei José},
    title     = {De Portugalliae ortu, Regni initiis et denique de rebus à Regibus, vniuersoque Regno praeclare gestis, compendium},
    year      = {1583},
    publisher = {apud Joannem Mettayer},
    address   = {Parisiis},
    keywords  = {sigla},
    shorthand = {TP},
}
@Book{maffei1559commentariorum,
    author    = {Volaterrano, R.},
    title     = {Commentariorum urbanorum Raphaelis Volaterrani, octo et triginta libri, accuratius quam antehac excusi},
    year      = {1559},
    publisher = {apud Frobenium et Episcopium},
    url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=QeaEVzCCoVcC},
    address   = {Basileae},
    keywords  = {sigla},
    shorthand = {VCom},
}
@Book{ThorndikeLynn1949TSoS,
    author    = {Thorndike, Lynn and Sacro Bosco, Joannes de and Robertus and Scot, Michael and Cecco},
    title     = {The Sphere of Sacrobosco and its commentators},
    year      = {1949},
    language  = {lat;eng},
    series    = {Corpus of mediaeval scientific texts ; v. 2},
    publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
    address   = {Chicago},
    keywords  = {Sacro Bosco, Joannes de, active 1230. Sphaera mundi -- Commentaries; Astronomy -- Early works to 1800; Science, Medieval -- sigla},
    shorthand = {SacSph},
}
@Misc{itinerariumantonini1518,
    title     = {Pomponius Mela. Julius Solinus. Itinerarium Antonini Aug. Vibius Sequester. P. Victor de regionibus urbis Romae. Dionysius Afer de Situ orbis Prisciano interprete},
    year      = {1518},
    address   = {Venetiis},
    chapter   = {Itinerarium Antonini Augusti},
    keywords  = {Itinerarium Antonini (edição séc. XVI) -- Toponímia (latina) -- Império Romano -- sigla},
    publisher = {in aedibus Aldi et Andreae soceri},
    shorthand = {IA},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}

\printbiblist[title={Lista de abreviaturas}]{shorthand}

\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I was reediting my question but I am afraid some of the code is out of the box (the code is there anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

At least in this example I see no reason for the slightly odd style combination `style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,` in particular when used together with `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}\setlength{\biblabelsep}{3pt}`. The `style=numeric,` will force a numeric-style bibliography here where the natural alignment for the citation labels (usually numbers) is different from the natural alignment of abbreviations in a list not based on numeric style.

Things look much, much more natural in this example when you just go for `style=authoryear,` and let the default settings sort the rest out (i.e. drop the `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}` and `\setlength{\biblabelsep}{3pt}`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  doi=false, url=false, isbn=false
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{barreiros1968chorographia,
    author    = {Barreiros, G.},
    title     = {Chorographia de alguns lugares [...]},
    year      = {1561},
    publisher = {por Ioã Aluarez},
    url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=h3-RngEACAAJ},
    address   = {em Coimbra},
    shorthand = {BCor},
}
@Book{Teixeira1583,
    author    = {Teixeira, frei José},
    title     = {De Portugalliae ortu, Regni initiis et denique de rebus à Regibus,
                 vniuersoque Regno praeclare gestis, compendium},
    year      = {1583},
    publisher = {apud Joannem Mettayer},
    address   = {Parisiis},
    shorthand = {TP},
}
@Book{maffei1559commentariorum,
    author    = {Volaterrano, R.},
    title     = {Commentariorum urbanorum Raphaelis Volaterrani,
                 octo et triginta libri, accuratius quam antehac excusi},
    year      = {1559},
    publisher = {apud Frobenium et Episcopium},
    url       = {https://books.google.pt/books?id=QeaEVzCCoVcC},
    address   = {Basileae},
    shorthand = {VCom},
}
@Book{ThorndikeLynn1949TSoS,
    author    = {Thorndike, Lynn and Sacro Bosco, Joannes de and Robertus
                 and Scot, Michael and Cecco},
    title     = {The Sphere of Sacrobosco and its commentators},
    year      = {1949},
    language  = {lat;eng},
    series    = {Corpus of mediaeval scientific texts ; v. 2},
    publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
    address   = {Chicago},
    shorthand = {SacSph},
}
@Misc{itinerariumantonini1518,
    title     = {Pomponius Mela. Julius Solinus.
                 Itinerarium Antonini Aug. Vibius Sequester. 
                 P. Victor de regionibus urbis Romae.
                 Dionysius Afer de Situ orbis Prisciano interprete},
    year      = {1518},
    address   = {Venetiis},
    chapter   = {Itinerarium Antonini Augusti},
    publisher = {in aedibus Aldi et Andreae soceri},
    shorthand = {IA},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbiblist[title={Lista de abreviaturas}]{shorthand}

\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: List of abbreviations with left-aligned abbreviations.]

Comment: That's way more readable!